# How to dynamically add objects to scene?

Tags: webgl

I have to write a program in which i should be able to click a button "add cube" and there will be added as many cubes as I want into the scene. I must be able to select any of them and move around. I managed to create one (hardcoded) cube and apply scaling and translation to it.

I tried to create a class "cube" and invoke intitialization and render as part of an object but didnt work as expected. Here is the working example for one cube and its transformations (note only the scaling and translation work)

HTML:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
  <title>Lab 0</title>

  <script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

    attribute  vec4 vPosition;
    attribute  vec4 vColors;
    varying vec4 fragColor;

    uniform vec3 theta;
    uniform float coeff;
    uniform vec3 trCoeff;

    uniform mat4 modelView;
    uniform mat4 projection;

    vec3 angles = radians( theta );
    void main() {

      vec3 angles = radians( theta );
      vec3 c = cos( angles );
      vec3 s = sin( angles );

      // Remeber: thse matrices are column-major
      mat4 rx = mat4( 1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0,
      0.0,  c.x,  s.x, 0.0,
      0.0, -s.x,  c.x, 0.0,
      0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0 );

  mat4 ry = mat4( c.y, 0.0, -s.y, 0.0,
      0.0, 1.0,  0.0, 0.0,
      s.y, 0.0,  c.y, 0.0,
      0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0 );


  mat4 rz = mat4( c.z, s.z, 0.0, 0.0,
      -s.z,  c.z, 0.0, 0.0,
      0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
      0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

  mat4 sc = mat4(
    coeff, 0, 0, 0,
    0, coeff, 0, 0,
    0, 0, coeff, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1
  );

  mat4 tr = mat4(
    1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    trCoeff.x, trCoeff.y, trCoeff.z, 1
  );

    fragColor = vColors;
    //projection * modelView *
    gl_Position =  tr * rz * ry * rx * sc * vPosition;
    }
  </script>

  <script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    precision mediump float;
    varying vec4 fragColor;

    void main() {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(fragColor);
    }
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="webgl-utils.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="initShaders.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="MV.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="shape0.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="gl-canvas" width="512" height="512">
    Oops ... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element
  </canvas>
</body>
<p> </p>
<button id="xButton">Rotate X</button>
<button id="yButton">Rotate Y</button>
<button id="zButton">Rotate Z</button>
<button id="stopButton">Stop Fucking Rotation</button>
<p> </p>

<button id="sUpButton">Scale Up</button>
<button id="sDownButton">Scale Down</button>
<p> </p>

<button id="leftButton">Left</button>
<button id="rightButton">Right</button>
<button id="upButton">Up</button>
<button id="downButton">Down</button>
<button id="closeButton">Closer</button>
<button id="furtherButton">Further</button>

<p> </p>
<button id="Button1">Increase Z</button>
<button id="Button2">Decrease Z</button>
<button id="Button3">Increase R</button>
<button id="Button4">Decrease R</button>

<p> </p>
<button id="Button5">Increase theta</button>
<button id="Button6">Decrease theta</button>
<button id="Button7">Increase phi</button>
<button id="Button8">Decrease phi</button>
<p> </p>

</html>
```

JS:

```
"use strict"

var canvas;
var gl;

var thetaRot = [10, 10, 10];
var thetaLoc;
var coeff = 1;
var coeffLoc;
var trCoeff = [0, 0, 0];
var trCoeffLoc;

var flag = true;
var axis = 0;

var xAxis = 0;
var yAxis = 1;
var zAxis = 2;

var near = 0.3;
var far = 3.0;
var radius = 4.0;
var theta = 0.0;
var phi = 0.0;
var dr = 5.0 * Math.PI / 180.0;

var fovy = 45.0;  // Field-of-view in Y direction angle (in degrees)
var aspect;       // Viewport aspect ratio

var mvMatrix, pMatrix;
var modelView, projection;
var eye;
const at = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
const up = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

var coord = {
  // For cube
  '1': vec3(0.1, 0.1, 0.1),
  '2': vec3(0.5, 0.1, 0.1),
  '3': vec3(0.5, 0.1, 0.5),
  '4': vec3(0.1, 0.1, 0.5),
  '5': vec3(0.1, 0.5, 0.1),
  '6': vec3(0.1, 0.5, 0.5),
  '7': vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5),
  '8': vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.1),

}

var vertices = [
  // For cube
  coord[4], coord[3], coord[2],
  coord[2], coord[4], coord[1],
  coord[1], coord[2], coord[5],
  coord[5], coord[8], coord[2],
  coord[2], coord[3], coord[8],
  coord[8], coord[3], coord[7],
  coord[7], coord[3], coord[4],
  coord[4], coord[7], coord[6],
  coord[6], coord[4], coord[1],
  coord[1], coord[5], coord[6],
  coord[6], coord[7], coord[8],
  coord[8], coord[6], coord[5],

]

var colors = [
  // each face of the cube
  0, 0, 1, 1.0,
  0, 0, 1, 1.0,
  0, 0, 1, 1.0,
  0, 0, 1, 1.0,
  0, 0, 1, 1.0,
  0, 0, 1, 1.0,

  0, 1, 0, 1.0,
  0, 1, 0, 1.0,
  0, 1, 0, 1.0,
  0, 1, 0, 1.0,
  0, 1, 0, 1.0,
  0, 1, 0, 1.0,

  0, 0.7, 1, 1.0,
  0, 0.7, 1, 1.0,
  0, 0.7, 1, 1.0,
  0, 0.7, 1, 1.0,
  0, 0.7, 1, 1.0,
  0, 0.7, 1, 1.0,

  0.5, 0, 1, 1.0,
  0.5, 0, 1, 1.0,
  0.5, 0, 1, 1.0,
  0.5, 0, 1, 1.0,
  0.5, 0, 1, 1.0,
  0.5, 0, 1, 1.0,

  1, 0, 0, 1.0,
  1, 0, 0, 1.0,
  1, 0, 0, 1.0,
  1, 0, 0, 1.0,
  1, 0, 0, 1.0,
  1, 0, 0, 1.0,

  0.2, 0, 1, 1.0,
  0.2, 0, 1, 1.0,
  0.2, 0, 1, 1.0,
  0.2, 0, 1, 1.0,
  0.2, 0, 1, 1.0,
  0.2, 0, 1, 1.0,

]

// add vertices for cone


window.onload = init;

function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");

  gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL(canvas);

  if (!gl) { alert("WebGL isn't available"); }

  aspect = canvas.width / canvas.height;

  var program = initShaders(gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader");
  gl.useProgram(program);

  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);


  var bufferId = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferId);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 50000, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, flatten(vertices));

  var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);

  var bufferColor = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferColor);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  var vColors = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vColors");
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(vColors, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 4 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, 0);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vColors);

  thetaLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "theta");


  document.getElementById("xButton").onclick = function () {
    flag = false
    axis = xAxis;
  };
  document.getElementById("yButton").onclick = function () {
    flag = false
    axis = yAxis;
  };
  document.getElementById("zButton").onclick = function () {
    flag = false
    axis = zAxis;
  };
  document.getElementById("stopButton").onclick = function () {
    flag = true;
  };


  document.getElementById("sUpButton").onclick = function () {
    coeff += 0.1;
  };
  document.getElementById("sDownButton").onclick = function () {
    coeff -= 0.1;
  };



  document.getElementById("leftButton").onclick = function () {
    trCoeff[0] -= 0.1;
  };
  document.getElementById("rightButton").onclick = function () {
    trCoeff[0] += 0.1;
  };
  document.getElementById("upButton").onclick = function () {
    trCoeff[1] += 0.1;
  };
  document.getElementById("downButton").onclick = function () {
    trCoeff[1] -= 0.1;
  };
  document.getElementById("closeButton").onclick = function () {
    trCoeff[2] += 0.1;
  };
  document.getElementById("furtherButton").onclick = function () {
    trCoeff[2] -= 0.1;
  };

  modelView = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "modelView");
  projection = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "projection");

  document.getElementById("Button1").onclick = function () { near *= 1.1; far *= 1.1; };
  document.getElementById("Button2").onclick = function () { near *= 0.9; far *= 0.9; };
  document.getElementById("Button3").onclick = function () { radius *= 2.0; };
  document.getElementById("Button4").onclick = function () { radius *= 0.5; };
  document.getElementById("Button5").onclick = function () { theta += dr; };
  document.getElementById("Button6").onclick = function () { theta -= dr; };
  document.getElementById("Button7").onclick = function () { phi += dr; };
  document.getElementById("Button8").onclick = function () { phi -= dr; };

  coeffLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "coeff");
  trCoeffLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "trCoeff");



  render();
}

function render() {
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  if (!flag) {
    thetaRot[axis] += 2.0;
  }
  gl.uniform3fv(thetaLoc, thetaRot);
  gl.uniform1f(coeffLoc, coeff);
  gl.uniform3fv(trCoeffLoc, trCoeff);


  eye = vec3(radius * Math.sin(theta) * Math.cos(phi),
    radius * Math.sin(theta) * Math.sin(phi), radius * Math.cos(theta));
  mvMatrix = lookAt(eye, at, up);
  pMatrix = perspective(fovy, aspect, near, far);

  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(modelView, false, flatten(mvMatrix));
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(projection, false, flatten(pMatrix));

  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.length);

  requestAnimFrame(render);
}
```

I expect managing to add an infinite amount of object (or until I run out of ram) to the scene and to apply transformations to one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebGL just draws pixels. It doesn't have a concept of a "Scene" and "objects". All of that is 100% up to you. How you represent objects and how you represent the scene is completely up to you. One example

```
const scene = [];

function addNewObjectToScene() {
  const obj = {
     x: Math.random() * 400,
     y: Math.random() * 400,
  }; 
  scene.push(obj);
}
```

Now add a button or a timer or whatever you want to call `addNewObjectToScene`

In your own code you'd have a `render` or `drawScene` function that goes over your "scene" and draws each object

```
function render() {
   for (const object of scene) {
     gl.useProgram(whateverShaderProgramCurrentObjectNeeds);

     // setBuffersAndAttributes for object
     // for each attribute in object
     //   gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferForThisAttribute)
     //   gl.enableVertexAttribArray(locationForThisAttrubute);
     //   gl.vertexAttribPointer(locationForThisAttibute, other settings for this attribute)

     // set any uniforms. This is probably where you'd use x and y from the code above
     // example:
     //   gl.uniform2f(offsetUniformLocation, object.x, object.y);

     // now draw
     // gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements with how ever many vertices are in the current object.

   }
}
```

How you organize your "scene" and what's in your objects is entire up to you. Three.js makes a scene from an object called `THREE.Object3D` each of which contains array of "children". This forms a scene graph.

Other apps do different things.

Being able to select one is also way too big a topic. What does "select" mean. Can you have an HTML `<select>` form where you pick from a dropdown list which object you want to select? Maybe there is an `<input type="text">` element where you type the name of the object you want to select?

If you want to click on objects, well now you've got a way too broad of a topic to cover. You could store collision data for each object. You could compute the position of each triangle your data makes and see if the mouse hit. You could use GPU picking where you draw the scene with each object in a different color using different shaders and then look at the pixel under the mouse to see what color it is effectively telling you want object was chosen. But all of this is dependent on how you created your scene.

Suggest you [read some tutorials on WebGL](https://webglfundamentals.org) and on [drawing multiple things](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-drawing-multiple-things.html) and maybe [a scene graph](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-scene-graph.html)